# htaccess is not working in an special case

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on a htaccess URL rewriting assignment.
My actaul URL is

`blabla.comqid=1&qtitle=what-is-css`

I have riwritten it using htaccess like

```
blabla.com/1/what-is-css
```

Now i am adding an another query string for sharing, the new URL must be like

```
blabla.com/1/what-is-css?share=asadas_45asd_asdasd-4744
```

My current htaccess code is below

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.html?question=$1&qtitle=$2

RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.html?question=$1
```

So basically there are three optional query strings, two of them should be rewritten and one of them will not be rewritten.

Comment: Just append the query string `[QSA]` in your first rule.

Comment: Like @Jan said - append [QSA] to your first rule. Read more about it [HERE](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA)

Comment: thanks @Jan, its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the records (in addition to my comment above):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.html?question=$1&qtitle=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.html?question=$1
```